# Why does using different URLs in WordPress settings cause a "Publishing failed, you are offline" error?

Tags: block-editor, site-url, cdn, home-url, classic-editor

In the WordPress General > Settings, when we update the WordPress address and the Site address to two different URLs We're not able to update/create posts. It is throwing an error saying "Publishing failed. You are probably offline."

Example:

- *Wordpress address:* https://origin.domain.com
- *Site address:* https://www.domain.com

Additional points:

- We're able to update the title or other contents from the Quick Edit option under each post, this happens only when we click on the "Edit"
- When using "Classic Editor", we're able to update/create posts without any issue
- We've cleared the cache/cookies and also tried in various other browsers and devices

Reason for such a requirement:

- The reason we're in need of such a set up is to use CDN via CloudFront
- The origin sub-domain will be pointing to our server's IP and will be used to serve as an origin for the CloudFront distribution
- Whereas the www sub-domain will be pointing to the xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net distribution's URL
- The www will be the URL for the end-users and all the pages and the assets will be served via CloudFront and the origin IP will be masked

Queries:

- Why this behaviour? If different URLs shouldn't be used why does WP allow it?
- And why this is working in the Classic Editor but not in the Gutenberg editor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's more to this than you've described, most likely a more specific error in the block editor, either in a banner or in the browsers dev tools, and most likely related to the REST API. Note that those settings are not the only places that will use the URLs, if you change a WP installs URL changing that setting will change a lot of places but it can't change all the hardcoded strings and serialised data structures in options and post meta that refer to the old URLs.

Comment: Tried this in several fresh WordPress installs but still this behavior existed. Why? Also noticed the URLs in options, posts and user tables, updated them using search and replace plugins but still the same behavior exists. Could this be a bug in WordPress?

Comment: Thanks for your response @TomJNowell. Additionally, We noticed that this issue doesn't occur when both the URLs are the same. i.e., WordPress and Site address are the same.

Comment: hmm did you check the browsers dev tools network panel? The message you're describing doesn't contain much technical information, the console and the network panel will hold more information, particularly requests to the REST API. Without this information the nature of your problem will be extremely difficult to identify, especially since you should not be seeing this issue it should not be happening.

Comment: some quick searches reveal https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23942. The chances that this is because WP does not support differing URLs are vanishingly small, lots of websites do that and do not have your issue. It's much more likely that the way your sites are configured prevents the block editor JS from contacting the REST API, e.g. if your editor is trying to access a domain that's not accessible unless you're the CDN provider

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, will look into the dev tools too and see if we've more information to debug this.